# Is it possible to import a .dae mesh file, with its materials, into a webots world?

Tags: simulation, webots

I don't have an example right now (not at my computer), but I'm hoping to be able to import a world designed, modelled, and textured in Blender (poly count isn't an issue).

I can import the model as a Solid -> Shape -> Mesh -> `.dae` file. Then I have to add an Appearance node to give it any kind of shading. But the `.dae` file already has colours and textures (as appearing in Blender 3D), but I haven't seen it show up in Webots.

Am I maybe missing a step? I'm after even simple colours so the entire environment isn't a single colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [CadShape](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/cadshape) instead of a [Mesh](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/mesh), so that both the mesh and the material are taken from the Collada (.dae file): `Solid` -> `CadShape` -> `.dae file`. You should also ensure that the textures referred to by the Collada file can be found relatively to the Collada file (which should be normally the case if you export the Collada file from Blender directly inside your local `protos/meshes` folder). If that's not the case, you can open the Collada file in a text editor and fix the paths to the textures.

*Disclaimer: I am a [Webots](https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots) developer working at [Cyberbotics](https://cyberbotics.com).*